# NUnit and Continuous Integration with Jenkins: which NUnit-files are needed?

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

at the moment I am trying to set up automatic testing on Jenkins. I have a Visual Studio Solution that contains 4 different projects, one of them is my NUnit test project with several tests on the other 3 projects.

**1** 
I added a PostBuild-Event to my Nunit test project in Visual Studio with the following content:

```
`$(SolutionDir)Libs\NUnit-2.6.0.12051\bin\nunit-console.exe $(TargetPath)`
```

It works fine, but is this the typical way to go?
The Test project is the last one in my build order, I don't think it makes sense to add PostBuild Events to the 3 other projects?

---

**2** 
As you can see on the path given above, my Visual Studio project folder has a folder that is called "Libs". This is where I put my dependencies in, also NUnit. But the NUnit folder has around 8MB. Can you tell me which files I can delete? Because otherwise on every commit to the source control, the users have to transmit 8MB only for NUnit which is a bit much I think.

I definitely need nunit.framework.dll in order to build the tests. I also need console-runner.exe in order to run the tests. But what else do I need? Unfortunately, console-runnter.exe has dependecies on some other files and crashes without them.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have been using a slightly different approach to integrating NUnit with Visual Studio (C#, MSBuild) under Jenkins.  The VS Solution contains several projects underneath it that build around 10 DLLs and 1 Application.   The Visual Studio Solution does not invoke NUnit.

Sitting alongside the "application" code is a directory containing the test code.  There is  a Test solution that is built independently.  It references the output of the application solution.

Both Visual Studio and NUnit are installed as applications on the build machine running Jenkins.

Our basic directory layout

- Components

  - bin (created)
  - Various source directories
  - Component.sln
- Tests

  - bin (created)
  - Various NUnit test case sources
  - Tests.sln

The Basic Build Steps in Jenkins

1. Using an MSBuild step, MSBuild Components/Components.sln
2. Using an MSBuild step, MSBuild Test/Test.sln
3. Using a Windows Batch File step, Invoke NUnit on Tests/Tests.sln:

   `nunit-console.exe Tests\Tests.sln /xml=nunit-test-results.xml /labels`
4. Setup a post build action using the xUnit Jenkins Plugin to process `nunit-test-results.xml` and display the results.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 2 questions:

1. I use a post build event on my Test project to run the NUnit console in the same way as you've described. Works well in our environment.
2. As you've said you need to include `nunit.framework.dll` to **build** your tests. To **run** them, the NUnit console will run quite happily with just the following files:

   ```
   bin\nunit-console.exe
   bin\nunit-console.exe.config
   bin\lib\nunit.core.dll
   bin\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll
   bin\lib\nunit.util.dll
   bin\lib\nunit-console-runner.dll
   ```

   This amounts to about 500KB of files for NUnit 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a script file instead of having multiple steps defined in Jenkins. We use powershell to call msbuild and nunit-console. That way, our developers can simply call this one powershell script prior to committing. It is also a lot easier to setup Jenkins (or any other build server) if the build/test/bundle/deploy steps are self-contained.